# Sort alphabeticaly and limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I have problem with sorting users by `name` and getting next item. 
How to get users with `name` < "Alf" i.e. users with names "Big", "Bob","Rob" etc. ? 
And for another example `name` < "Big", so users with names "Bob","Rob" will get selected.

How can I get sorted users by name with where query applied?

Comment: I am not sure what you really want to do... 
Did you try: `User.order('name ASC') ?

Comment: Are you using `mySQL` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following,

```
User.where('name > ?', 'Big').order(:name)
```

Comment: So simple.. :D @ray THX